# Continuity of $L^1$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I know that in general norms in a topological vector space are continous maps, that is to say:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \|x_n\|=\|\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n \|$$

But this is not always the case in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (because we cannot always swap integral and limit). I know that I'm missing something stupid but please help me.

Comment: It *is* the case in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ (as you said: it holds in any normed vector space $E$). For any *convergent* sequence $(x_n)$ in $E$, i.e. $\lim\|x_n-x\|=0$ for some $x\in E$, prove that $\lim\|x_n\|=\|x\|$ (use triangular inequality).

Comment: In $L^1$ this means : if $\int|f_n-f|\to0$ then $\int|f_n|\to\int|f|$.

Comment: Clearly the limit in the norm should be interpreted as a limit with respect to the metric of $L^1$ and not as the standard punctual convergence limit: usually the notation $\lim$ is not used for the limit with respect to the mettic of $L^1$. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand whether you agree or not. I *did* "interpret the limit in the norm as a limit with respect to the metric of $L^1$". The notation $\lim$ is used for the limit in *any* Hausdorff space.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I was just observing that my misunderstanding was in the fact that the notation $\lim$ can have multiple interpretation. If we interpret it as the limit with respect to the metric of $L^1$ than this is true. If we interpret it as the classical punctual limit of functions, than it's clearly false (because you cannot always swap integral and limit).